# Plusquamperfekt usage

Tags: tense

Would someone please explain the differences in meaning of these three sentences:

> 1. Wir mussten umdrehen und höher in Richtung unserer Plätze gehen, doch bevor wir unsere Reihe **erreicht haben**, gab es einen riesigen Jubel.
> 2. Wir mussten umdrehen und höher in Richtung unserer Plätze gehen, doch bevor wir unsere Reihe **erreicht hatten**, gab es einen riesigen Jubel.
> 3. Wir mussten umdrehen und höher in Richtung unserer Plätze gehen, doch bevor wir unsere Reihe **erreichten**, gab es einen riesigen Jubel.

Comment: I took the liberty of bolding the differences. There are all three German past tenses here, preterite, perfect and pluperfect.

Answer (score 2):

The logic of events, the order of sentences, and the conjunction "bevor" all define the time order of events in this sentence so well that the three example sentences can only differ in nuances.

Let's start with **example (3)**: all the clauses are in Präteritum, which only says that everything happened in the past, and the sequence of events becomes clear from "bevor" and the order of sentences. This use of Präteritum is pretty normal for what you would find in a work of fiction or a written report of events.

The obvious order of events is: *(I'm using present tense here as the basic form.)*
a) Wir müssen umdrehen und (danach) höher in Richtung unserer Plätze gehen.
b) Es gibt einen riesigen Jubel.
c) Wir erreichen unsere Reihe.

**Example (2)** is almost the same, but it uses a different time reference point for (c). "Bevor" doesn't refer to "die Reihe erreichen" *(reaching the row)* but to "die Reihe erreicht haben" *(having reached the row)*.

So in this case, again set to present, part (c) becomes

c) Wir haben unsere Reihe erreicht.

Note how although this is grammatically perfect tense, much like in English, it is a statement about a *current state of things*, a state in present tense, that is a result of something that was completed (or in latin: *perfectum*) in the past. This past, set to the past, becomes a Plusquamperfekt in the sentence.

**Example (1)** is an odd mixture of Perfekt and Präteritum that doesn't fit together here. This mix can be used in spoken language, but in written language it's the only one of the three examples that can be called incorrect.

**Some more variants that would be correct:**

*Everything in perfect tense (like in an oral recount):*

4. Wir haben umdrehen und höher in Richtung unserer Plätze gehen müssen, doch bevor wir unsere Reihe erreicht haben, hat es einen riesigen Jubel gegeben.

*Same but with the completed "erreicht haben" as a reference point:*

5. Wir haben umdrehen und höher in Richtung unserer Plätze gehen müssen, doch bevor wir unsere Reihe erreicht **hatten**, hat es einen riesigen Jubel gegeben.

*Present tense with "erreicht haben" as a reference point:*

6. Wir müssen umdrehen und höher in Richtung unserer Plätze gehen, doch bevor wir unsere Reihe erreicht haben, gibt es einen riesigen Jubel.

*Same sentence in Futur peppered with some Futur II. Utterly useless, no one would say this, but just for ... well ... "fun":*

7. Wir werden umdrehen und höher in Richtung unserer Plätze gehen müssen, doch bevor wir unsere Reihe erreicht haben werden, wird es einen riesigen Jubel geben.

Comment: The difference between 2) and 3) becomes clearer with other predicates: *bevor wir die Zigarren rauchten* vs. *bevor wir die Zigarren geraucht hatten*.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, all three examples show wrong usage of tenses. Let's look at why so first; your question about differences in meaning will be adressed last.

## What's the keyword?

The keyword is '**bevor**', engl. *before*, indicating that what's next (=Jubel) happened prior to what it refers to (=erreichten).

## When to use pluperfect?

The pluperfect is used to relate to an action (1) that occurred **prior** to an aforementioned time in the past (2).

(1) in your example is the action of 'riesigen Jubel', which occured prior to

(2) the arrival back there, which happened afterwards.

Thus, it is 'einen riesigen Jubel geben' that needs to be set to pluperfect.

## How to use pluperfect?

The pluperfect is built by combining the verbs participle II with the preterite form of *sein* or *haben*, which are conjugated.

- Riesigen Jubel geben *- infinite clause*
- Es gibt riesigen Jubel *- finite clause with Vorfeld, in present time*
- **Es hatte riesigen Jubel gegeben** *- finite clause with Vorfeld, in pluperfect time*.

## First result

Your example reads

> Wir mussten umdrehen und höher in Richtung unserer Plätze gehen, doch bevor wir unsere Reihe erreichten, hatte es einen riesigen Jubel gegeben.

This sentence is grammatically correct, but somewhat ugly without further context, because the usages of 'doch' (konzessiv) and of pluperfect, as well as the fact the sentence ends in it, stress out the part in pluperfect. So, the reader would now **expect further information** about 'why' and/or 'what then?', i.e. the cause of 'Jubel' and some actions up next. When this is not provided, and the text continues somewhere/ somewhen else, it's expected the text remains in preterite.

## Possible upgrade

Depending on how the text continues (see above), a stylisticly better phraseing could be

> Wir mussten umdrehen und höher in Richtung unserer Plätze gehen, doch unterwegs gab es einen riesigen Jubel.

## Differences in meaning

Despite all three example sentences being grammatically wrong, their meaning (something that's established by the receiver, not the transmitter, but let's ignore this for once)  is identical to the correct one; no obfuscation here. This holds in general, because the inclusion of **keywords** s.a. 'bevor', 'nachdem' is sufficient (and dominant) to indicate a timeline.

Answer (score 0):

### Introduction

Language has many devices to establish a timeline of events. There are words like "bevor" (before, prior to), "nachdem" (after), "während" (during), etc., but there are also grammatical devices. For instance:

> Ich ziehe in das Haus, das ich gebaut habe.
> <sub>I move into the house i have built.</sub>

This states two things: first, the moving takes place now; and second, the building takes place *before* the moving starts. Compare that to:

> Ich zog in das Haus, das ich gebaut hatte.
> <sub>I moved into the house i had built.</sub>

The meaning in respect of the order of moving and building - build first, move later - is still the same, but now both actions are in the past. Notice that we could have used words too to emphasize the order (i.e. "I moved into the house i had built *before*.") but the grammatical device of *consecutio temporum* alone is already enough to carry the meaning.

The basic rule is the same in English and in German as well and it is:

> present tense / Präsens  <=>  present perfect tense / Perfekt
> past tense / Präteritum  <=>  past perfect tense / Plusquamperfekt

These successions express *Vorzeitigkeit* - the action expressed in the word in past perfect tense happens before the action expressed in the word in past tense.

This rule holds for relating events directly. Notice that one *can* forego explicitly stating the time and leave it to the common sense of the reader/hearer to figure that out:

> Ich zog in das Haus, das ich baute.
> <sub>I moved into the house i built.</sub>

Common sense may tell us the house was built before the move but language itself may leave that open. Alternatively we could use words to establish the timeline and forego the grammatical devices:

> Ich baute das Haus, dann zog ich ein.
> <sub>I built the house, then i moved in.</sub>

### Conclusion and Answer

After this lengthy introduction: your example #2 is following what i called "basic rule" above: the main sentence ("Wir mussten umdrehen...") is in *Präteritum* and hence an event in the past. The relative sentence ("bevor ... hatten") is in *Plusquamperfekt* and that signifies that what happens in this part was happening before something else ("gab es..."). The "bevor" is necessary in this case to introduce the relative sentence, but the usage of tenses alone already establishes the timeline.

Example #3 is also correct and typical for storytelling. (If it is a fictional story like a novel or just relating a past event doesn't matter.) Everything is in past tense (the storytelling time) and the timeline is established by "bevor".

Example #1 is just wrong: the succession of tenses (Präteritum - Perfekt) is simply wrong. What *would* have been possible is (but that only as an aside, it is of no concern here):

> Wir mussten umdrehen und höher in Richtung unserer Plätze gehen, doch bevor wir unsere Reihe **erreichen** **gibt** es einen riesigen Jubel.

This uses a certain narrative technique: the change to *Präsens* (present tense) to enhance the tension. The intended effect is to make the recipient more involved by making the story look like it happens *right now*.